# On the Convergence of a Telescoping Type Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any series such that
\begin{align*}
\sum a_{n}^{2}<\infty
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
\sum|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|=\infty?
\end{align*}

Of course, one shall not think of any monotone decreasing sequence $(a_{n})$ or else the later is just a telescoping series and hence convergent.

**EDIT:**

Tavish has provided a good answer to the above question. What if the condition $a_{n}\geq 0$ is assumed, is there any counterexample then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $$ works, as $$|a_{n+1} -a_n | = \left| \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \right | = \frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{n+1} $$ The series of this diverges. On the other hand, $$a_n^2 =\frac{1}{n^2} $$ which has a convergent series.

**Bonus Question: What if $a_n\ge 0$?**

In this case, just take something like  $$a_{2n} =e^{-n} +\frac 1n \\ a_{2n+1} = e^{-n} $$

Comment: Thanks to your solution. What if I require that $a_{n}\geq 0$?

Comment: @user284331 I have added something.